# JTextArea and DocumentFilter println current text

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, documentfilter

Ok, this may sound simple but still troubles me. I use a jtextarea and a document filter. I'd like as soon as the user presses "a" for example just the current text to be printed via println. I use:

```
public void replace(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text, AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {

    if ("a".equals(text)) {     
        String c = fb.toString();
        System.out.println(c);              
    }
    super.replace(fb, offset, length, text, attrs);
    }
}
```

I type "help", for example and get javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument$DefaultFilterBypass@6f9bb25a in console! But why? D: Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
String c = fb.getDocument().getText(0, fb.getDocument().getLength());
```

You're currently printing the FilterBypass object. You need to get the Document and get the text by passing the offset and the length of the document

Comment: you are my hero for today!

Comment: If a user inserts text at a point other than the end (i.e. at the start), this will always add the text to the end.